# Old HDD testing software

Tags: hard-drive

Good day! I was wondering if using older HDD testing software (Victoria) vs. a more recent one (HDTune) has any difference. Will the newer ones be more accurate? Has the HDD technology changed enough for it to matter?

Comment: Software designed to display the S.M.A.R.T data are all the same.

Comment: As both Victoria and HDTune include read/write tests, there may be some differences.  Compare the test lists (linea/funnel/random seek tests, surface scans, pattern tests, cache tests, etc), and wee if they differ.  Also, I'm not sure if Victoria supports SSDs, so you may not get wear level or other SSD specific data.

Comment: I guess I'll do some tests with multiple utilities to see if they will bring forth different results. Thanks for the quick responses guys!

Answer (score -1):

IMHO Victoria are more accurate because it can show you time of read of sectors. It is very helpful to locate "weak sectors". But HDDTune is more "comfortable" to use. You should give a try to HDDScan. It is like HDDTune but can check reading time of sector.

Comment: I received negative vote for this answer. Why? Wrong language (I still learn English)? Essential error?